# Why is margin-right not working in ionic + AngularJS?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a scrolling content div, whose content I want to give some margin-left as well as from right. It is taking margin-left, but not taking margin right. I set margin in %.

```html
<ion-scroll scrollbar-y="true" delegate-handle="invoicegrid" ng-style="viewHeight">
    <div style="margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%" class="row brd"" ng-repeat="column in invoice_records  track by $index" ng-class-odd="" ng-class="{white:$index%2 == 0,blue:$index%2 == 1}">
        <div class="col brdlrdt  collapse-sm" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="invoice_column_name[$index].checked && invoice_column_name[$index].fieldNameOrPath===field.fieldNameOrPath">{{field.value}}</div>
        <div class="col col-10 text-center brdlrdt collapse-sm"></div>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GsmbC75KuorL4nMftSWF?p=preview) example.

How can I get it to detect my margin-right setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The css in ionic.css sets elements with the class "row" to a width of 100%. When you add margins, the width of your row becomes 100% + 5% + 5%, and the row is wider than its container.

There are several ways to fix this.

1. You can remove width: 100%
2. You can add padding to the parent div (instead of margins on the rows)
3. Changing the position type

Comment: could you please give plunker

Comment: To the ion-scroll scrollbar, add  style="padding:0px 5%

Answer (score 0):

If someone still have this problem with Ionic, the solution for me was to not put my content inside the div with `class="row"`.

Comment: Hi Ridrigo, could you expand on this answer by listening where you put it, instead of `div class="row"`?